# Create a json script to get alerts from zabbix

Tags: json, zabbix

I want to get the alert from zabbix that says `"description": "Free disk space is less than 20% on volume D:"` but i just receive 1 alert even knowing that have more. Did i do something wrong?

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "method":"trigger.get",
   "params":{
      "expandData":"hostname",
      "output":[
         "triggerid",
         "description"
      ],
      "filter":{
         "value":1,
         "description":"Free disk space is less than 20% on volume D:"
      },
      "sortorder":"DESC"
   },
   "auth":"auth",
   "id":1
}
```

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. In addition, describe what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get alerts, but you are asking for triggers - **trigger.get**.

I'm not sure what do you really want to get, but probably you should to use:

```
alert.get
```

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/alert/get

OR

```
event.get
```

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/event/get